# How to rotate the device horizontally even when a user turn on the portrait orientation lock

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, landscape

I want to know how to rotate a device even when a user turns on the portrait orientation lock in iPhone.
Like the amazon prime video app, normally I see the app is in portrait mode, but when I start watching a movie, the app changes its rotation to horizontal even when I turn on the portrait orientation lock.

When I googled it, I only found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868872/force-rotate-ios-even-when-devices-portrait-orientation-lock-is-on), but using CoreMotion is the only way to achieve what I want to do??

I was using the following code to rotate the device from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift),

```
struct AppUtility {

    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {

        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            delegate.orientationLock = orientation
        }
    }

    /// OPTIONAL Added method to adjust lock and rotate to the desired orientation
    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {

        self.lockOrientation(orientation)

        UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
    }

}
```

But the app doesn't rotate from portrait to landscape automatically (from landscape to portrait works...), but when I rotate the device from portrait to landscape by my hand, the app's view rotates.

So, how can I make the device rotation to landscape when I'm into a specific view controller? (like the prime video app automatically turns the orientation to landscape when I start watching movie)

Answer (score 0):

in AppDelegate following variable to lock all the controllers with given orientation

```
var orientationLock  = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
```

Now implement following method in AppDelegate

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return self.orientationLock
}
```

Write these methods in separate Helper file

```
    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
    if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        delegate.orientationLock = orientation
    }
}

static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    lockOrientation(orientation)
    UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: LocalizedKey.orientation.string)
}
```

Call this method in your specific controller's viewWillAppear()

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    Helpers.lockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape,
                            andRotateTo: UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft)
}
```

NOTE: LocalizedKey.orientation.rawValue is string in separate file which have the value of "orientation"